# Google & Facebook Login will not write to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am working on Social Media logins. If I create an account from my application directly it works. I am now implementing Facebook and Google Account logins. I followed this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/integrating-social-login-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application

However, for some reason when I press signin for any of the two. It sends me to the login page for them but when it comes back it just sends me back to the sign in page but doesn't write anything to the db. My question is if this tutorial is still valid since it is 2017. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'merit', '= 3.0.1'
# Used to implement at.js for auto complete mentions/emojis
gem 'jquery-atwho-rails'

# Use twitter bootstrap sass
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# gem 'font-awesome-rails'
# gem 'font-awesome5-rails', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
gem 'font_awesome5_rails'

gem 'xbox_live_api'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'oj'

gem 'thredded', '~> 0.16.13'
gem 'rails-ujs'

group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.2.8'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

  # Use Dotenv for environment variables
  gem 'dotenv', '~> 2.2.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~>0.18'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'cloudinary'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'fog'
  gem 'fog-aws'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'public_activity'

gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'acts_as_follower'
gem 'counter_culture', '~> 0.1.33'

gem 'faker'
gem 'populator'
gem 'auto_html', '~>1.6.4'
gem 'sanitize'

gem 'active_model_serializers'

gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'round_robin_tournament'
gem 'tournament-system', '~> 2'
gem 'challonge-api'
gem 'tournament'

gem 'oauth2'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'

gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
gem 'opentok'

gem "omniauth", "~> 1.9.1"

# Use Omniauth Facebook plugin
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'

# Use Omniauth Google plugin
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

And this is what comes up on the terminal:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2021-04-06 20:41:47 -0700I, [2021-04-06T20:41:47.663699 #3568]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.5ms)  UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "sessions"."id" = ?  [["data", "BAh7CUkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjoGRUZJIjFrdTA2d0NtU05RWmhWazVuNjlt\nZjRxdmNHYTZQQ1E3ZUpLRTBYYnQzdXdNPQY7AEZJIhRvbW5pYXV0aC5wYXJh\nbXMGOwBUewBJIhRvbW5pYXV0aC5vcmlnaW4GOwBUIihodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxo\nb3N0OjMwMDAvdXNlcnMvc2lnbl91cEkiE29tbmlhdXRoLnN0YXRlBjsAVEki\nNTcwMzg2YjMxZTdiNzEwZGNiN2QyNzFmM2UwY2ZkMTdiMmM2Nzg3NGQwMTMx\nMjlkMwY7AEY=\n"], ["updated_at", 2021-04-07 03:41:47 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (8.2ms)  commit transaction
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=70386b31e7b710dcb7d271f3e0cfd17b2c67874d013129d3&code=4%2F0AY0e-g6AHjEU9GwqapLtEAOhufzwoWKoghn00mG581GfaBvzapzjD0ggbBwrjG3v1J6tvQ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none" for ::1 at 2021-04-06 20:41:47 -0700
I, [2021-04-06T20:41:48.012890 #3568]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"70386b31e7b710dcb7d271f3e0cfd17b2c67874d013129d3", "code"=>"4/0AY0e-g6AHjEU9GwqapLtEAOhufzwoWKoghn00mG581GfaBvzapzjD0ggbBwrjG3v1J6tvQ", "scope"=>"email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid", "authuser"=>"0", "prompt"=>"none"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? AND "users"."uid" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "118353543471926940974"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "ben875717@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 69ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "sessions"."id" = ?  [["data", "BAh7B0kiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjoGRUZJIjFrdTA2d0NtU05RWmhWazVuNjlt\nZjRxdmNHYTZQQ1E3ZUpLRTBYYnQzdXdNPQY7AEZJIgpmbGFzaAY7AFR7B0ki\nDGRpc2NhcmQGOwBUWwBJIgxmbGFzaGVzBjsAVHsGSSIKZXJyb3IGOwBGSSJg\nVGhlcmUgd2FzIGEgcHJvYmxlbSBzaWduaW5nIHlvdSBpbiB0aHJvdWdoIEdv\nb2dsZS4gUGxlYXNlIHJlZ2lzdGVyIG9yIHRyeSBzaWduaW5nIGluIGxhdGVy\nLgY7AFQ=\n"], ["updated_at", 2021-04-07 03:41:48 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (6.4ms)  commit transaction
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for ::1 at 2021-04-06 20:41:48 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 300ms (Views: 298.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "sessions"."id" = ?  [["data", "BAh7BkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjoGRUZJIjFrdTA2d0NtU05RWmhWazVuNjlt\nZjRxdmNHYTZQQ1E3ZUpLRTBYYnQzdXdNPQY7AEY=\n"], ["updated_at", 2021-04-07 03:41:48 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (6.6ms)  commit transaction
```

Any advice would be appriciated.

Edited adding User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_merit

belongs_to :referrer, :class_name => 'User', foreign_key: 'referred_by'

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
    :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook, :google_oauth2]
acts_as_voter
acts_as_follower
acts_as_followable

has_many :posts
has_many :comments
has_many :events
has_many :tourneys
has_many :players
has_many :accounts
has_many :party_rooms
has_many :invitations

has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id

before_create :generate_ref_token

#after_create :create_default_conversation
after_create :award_points_to_referrer
after_create :created_at_previous_change

mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
mount_uploader :cover, AvatarUploader

validates_presence_of :name

self.per_page = 10

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

def friends
    list = self.following_users.map do |user| 
        user if self.followed_by?(user)
    end

    list.compact.sort_by{ |user| user.name }
end

def upcoming_events
    list = self.events.where("event_datetime >= ?", Date.today)
    self.friends.each do |fr|
        list += fr.events.where("event_datetime >= ?", Date.today)
    end

    list.compact.sort_by{ |event| event.event_datetime }
end

def online?
    if current_sign_in_at.present? 
        last_sign_out_at.present? ? current_sign_in_at > last_sign_out_at : true
    else
        false
    end
end

def award_points_to_referrer
    if !self.referrer.nil?
        self.referrer.add_points(200, category: REFERRAL)
    end
end

def generate_ref_token
    if self.referral_token.nil?
        self.referral_token = loop do
            token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
            break token unless User.exists?(referral_token: token)
        end
    end
end

def self.create_from_provider_data(provider_data)
    where(provider: provider_data.provider, uid: provider_data.uid).first_or_create do | user |
        user.email = provider_data.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
        user.skip_confirmation!
    end
end
```

end

Comment: As far as I see there's a rollback, probably on User model. What validations do you have there?

Comment: I added my User Model to my post!

Comment: do you have any devise validations set up? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb